# Formatted SQL Changelogs with other extensions than .sql

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-sql

I am using Liquibase with Oracle. I have all the database objects in source files, for i.e., `./src/packages` and `./scr/views`

For the package spec, I am using `.pks` as file extension, and for the package body I am using `.pkb`.

For the views, I am using `.pls` as the file extension.

The reason behind these extension standards is because I can use SQLDev to open these files and it will know how to handle each file accordingly.

However, it seems these extensions bring some issues when using Liquibase and Formatted SQL Changelogs as Liquibase won't handle the `.pks`, `.pkb` or `.pls` as they were `.sql` files, even though they are.

So then I was wondering if there is any configuration in Liquibase where I could say: "hey, consider these extensions as sql files".

Comment: How do you include those files from your changelog?

Answer (score 0):

There is no configuration option to inform Liquibase of alternative extensions.
The `.sql` is hardcoded in the parser code like this:

`if (changeLogFile.endsWith(".sql"))`

see: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/parser/core/formattedsql/FormattedSqlChangeLogParser.java